# Error when using dvipng: "+tlig; source file could not be found"

Tags: luatex, miktex, png, dvi-mode

I am trying to use `dvipng` to compile `.tex` files to `.dvi` and then to convert it to `.png`. Here is the `test.tex` file that I am using as a minimum reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\title{Test}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
Document text body.
\end{document}
```

Then I sucecssfully compile it with:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi test.tex
```

When opening the `.dvi` file, I see that it has been generated correctly. Then, next, I try to convert the generated `test.dvi` file with:

```
dvipng test.dvi
```

But then I get 4 errors:

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:
>     The [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; source file could not be found.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:
>     PK font [lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; could not be created.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:
>     The [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; source file could not be found.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason:
>     PK font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; could not be created.

How could I solve that? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Can you convert PDF to PNG instead? Or use another engine?

Comment: LuaLaTeX is using opentype fonts and `dvipng` does not handle these fonts. (They are not in the list of supported font types for the binary in TeX Live, at least. I assume MikTeX is the same.)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for your comment! But is there a way to get `dvipng` those fonts or is it not flexible enough? In my case, using LuaLaTeX is imperative due to memory restrictions with other engines. Still, the final result must be converted to PNG files.

Comment: Why not using `standalone` with the `convert` option?

Comment: Opentype fonts aren't supported by `dvipng` according to its man page. Can't you use PDF output? Or @egreg's suggestion?

Comment: @cfr @egreg Thanks to you both. I was indeed able to solve the problem by using `standalone` with `magick` as the `convert` engine. Feel free to post an answer so I can mark it as accepted, if you wish.

Comment: @egreg ^^ You have mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program `dvipng` only supports standard `.tfm` fonts and is not able to use OpenType/TrueType fonts loaded by LuaTeX’s fontloader (or other similar method); *no* other DVI driver (notably `xdvi`) is able to, as far as I know.

You can do a direct conversion using `standalone` (run with `-shell-escape`) or postprocess the PDF file with a PDF to PNG utility such as ImageMagick.

```
\documentclass[convert,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\maketitle

Document text body.

\end{document}
```

[image]